# Array out of bounds in android for no reason

Tags: android

I was debugging my app, having it turned on and suddenly it crashed for no reason. It was running good for a few minutes. Normally this wouldn't be a problem since crashlogs help, but this time the crashlog is useless. Maybe you can see in here why it crashed?

```
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 302, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:390)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:732)
        at android.widget.ListView.correctTooHigh(ListView.java:1421)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1359)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1651)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:494)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

This is how I add the adapter to the ListView that i think is affected

```
    msgs = new CircularArray<Message>(helper.getAllMessages(), MSG_STACK_SIZE);
    if (msgs.getSize() > 0){
        sortedMessages.clear();
        sortedMessages.addAll(msgs.getAllSorted());
        createAdapter();
    }
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

`sortedMessages` is a field that is passed to the adapter's constructor in `createAdapter`. I also modify that list in a listener that is called from another thread:

```
    public void onNewMessage(Message msg) {
        msgs.add(msg);
        helper.insertMessage(msg);

        sortedMessages.clear();
        sortedMessages.addAll(msgs.getAllSorted());
        ChatFragment.this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                setSelection(adapter.getCount() - 1);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 302, size is 0`. What does "size is **0**" tell you? Is that a reason, maybe?

Comment: you are probably calling clear() on the collection while the Adapter is laying out its children

Comment: I know what it means, but its an error from ListView, nothing i can do about it.

Comment: Adding the part where you fill the ArrayList and assign it as an ArrayAdapter to the ListView would help.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Added.

Comment: is sortedMessages the collection you pass to the adapter ?

Comment: told you, you were calling clear on the same collection

Comment: @Blackbelt thank you, you are right. Am i right thinking that moving the operations on data set to be done on the UI thread will fix the problem?

Comment: it should, give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the arraylist in the adapter changed while the listview is drawing, you should call `notifyDatasetChanges` on the adapter wherever the list with the adapter is changed.

Regarding the snippets of your code:
you shouldn't update the list from multiple threads, make all the updates to the list from the ui thread and notify the adapter , like that you will avoid changing the list while the adapter getting a view for the list to draw

Comment: I am doing just that. But i think i know the problem. I think i should do the changes to the dataset on the UI thread, this way it wont both update the set and redraw the `ListView` at the same time.